# Why js event disappear?

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to add click event to elements with some class:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
jQuery(".myclass").each(function (index, value) {
        jQuery(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("asd");
        });
    });
    // breakpoint
)};
```

When the breakpoin is hit in firebug, I check click events of first myclass element in console and it has this event. When I click continue (in firebug) and the site finish to load, I check it again and it has no click event. Can you tell me why this event disappear?

Comment: what does `click continue and the site is loaded` mean? there isn't enough information given for anyone here to reproduce your issue

Comment: Unable to answer this question. Not enough details.

Comment: I edited my question. player was not important element.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really replicate an issue with the code you've posted, however you don't need to do a loop to add your event handling.

you can just:

```
jQuery(".myclass").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    player.onclick();
});
```

You'd also only need to pass through the event `e`, and prevent it if you are clicking on a `a` tag, `input type='submit'` etc

UPDATE: the reason your code is failing though, is because you have a syntax error, your `}` and `)` are the wrogn way round. try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
    jQuery(".myclass").each(function (index, value) {
        jQuery(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("asd");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I need a loop, because I will do other things with this elements, but it doesn't matter right now